# What group does this Cayley graph represent?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I have the following Cayley graph: 
$$ ...\cdot \leftrightarrow \cdot \leftrightsquigarrow \cdot \leftrightarrow \cdot \leftrightsquigarrow \cdot \leftrightarrow ...$$

Here are my thoughts: we have two generators $a,b$. And $a^2=b^2=e$ since we have arrows going out and back from $e$ to $a$ and $b$. So this group is the group of words $ababa...aba$ which can start and end with either $a$ or $b$. Is it the same as a free group with two relations: $\langle a, b\ |\ a^2, b^2\rangle$? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: I'm really not keen on 'a free group with two relations'.  There are relations, so it's not free.  You can call it a two-relator group.

Comment: But the terminology is almost correct: this is a free product of the two order 2 groups $\langle a \, | \, a^2\rangle \approx \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\langle b \, | \, b^2\rangle\approx \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. There are no further relations since there are no loops in the Cayley graph except those deducible from the relations $a^2 = b^2 = e$.

The group $\langle a, b \mid a^2, b^2 \rangle$ is known as the [infinite dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group).